# Virtualization of iOS

Tags: ios, virtual-machine, reverse-engineering

I am interested in analyzing the network traffic utilized by an app I found on the app store. I *could* just use wireshark to analyze the traffic on the network, but that would be too easy.

Instead, I would rather run the app on a virtualized instance of iOS.

Is it possible to run iOS in a virtual machine on OS X?

My initial search shows that this may be difficult because a lot of virtualization software is designed for the x86 architecture, and iOS runs on ARM architecture.

Has anybody gotten this to work before?

Comment: To mods looking to whether or not to close this, please use your own judgement, but I consider this on topic for SO because it is a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers". See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you cannot run regular Appstore apps on Simulator.
Instead, use jailbroken iDevice, install from Cydia tools like tcpdump, sslKillSwitch to monitor phone device traffic.

Other tricks you can find on [IOS app analysis website](http://highaltitudehacks.com)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to install iOS on VirtualBox because iOS is only for ARM-based processors, and VirtualBox does not support hardware emulation of the ARM architecture. Unlike Android, iOS isn't open source so you can't recompile it for x86 processors. Plus, you'd need to write a custom boot loader for iOS somehow.

A company called [Corellium](https://twitter.com/CorelliumHQ) is claiming to be the first business to offer a virtualized iOS device experience to developers and testers. The company is defining this as the "future of mobile development" which will give developers instant access to run their creations on virtualized iPhones and iPads on a Mac or PC which are running actual real versions of iOS.